# MongoDB convert object to array and apply filter

Tags: mongodb

I would like to perform a query in MongoDB. Given a document like this, where the keys of the inner object are "random":

```
{
  "replies": {
    "abcdefgh4343daj": {
      date: 2022-07-27T14:47:10.025Z,  
    },
    "1235fsedfseaww": {
      date: 2022-06-27T14:47:10.025Z,
    },
    "u89ues89fes8fse": {
      date: 2022-08-27T14:47:10.025Z,
    },
  }
}
```

I would like to Query `replies` and return an Array of all the objects that their date is smaller than `2022-07-28T14:47:10.025Z`:

```
[{name: "abcdefgh4343daj", date: 2022-07-27T14:47:10.025Z}, {name: "1235fsedfseaww", date: 2022-06-27T14:47:10.025Z}]
```

My idea was to apply first an aggregate with an `$objectToArray` and then apply a filter `$lt` to that result. But my problem is that I don't know how to perform `$objectToArray` when the object key is not known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {
        "$objectToArray": "$replies"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data" //To access array elements
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "$expr": {
        "$lte": [
          "$v.date",
          ISODate("2022-07-28T14:47:10.025Z")
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T2FkM1eBBeB)

Same idea has been translated into query.

You may need to group back to bring back original structure.

Comment: Thanks! I think it should be `$data.v.date` inside the `$lte` expression. Anyways, is there any way of returning this in a more readable format? Like an array with objects with a new key `name` and the other fields as is?

Comment: Well, I can do that just with a `$project`, thanks